# How to clear Tkinter ListBox Python

Tags: python, tkinter, listbox

How to clear a listbox when a button is clicked to re-populate it? The code below is giving me an error.

code:

```
self.listNodes.delete(0,END)
```

error:

```
NameError: name 'END' is not defined
```

Comment: Please provide a [mcve]. The code above isn't enough to reproduce the error.

Answer (score 32, accepted):

Depending on how you imported tkinter you may have to put end in quotations 
Try:

```
  self.listNodes.delete(0,'end')
```

you can also use:

```
self.listNodes.delete(0,tk.END)
```

Answer (score 3):

Replace:

```
self.listNodes.delete(0,END)
```

with:

```
self.listNodes.delete('0','end')
```

`END` is a variable of [tkinter](/questions/tagged/tkinter) module, which suggests either a wildcard(`from tkinter import *`) import or `from tkinter import END` was supposed to be used.

Answer (score 1):

You can use this is you imported tkinter as:

```
import tkinter as tk

self.listnodes.delete(0, tk.END)
```

Or you can do:

```
from tkinter import *

self.listnodes.delete(0, END)
```

Answer (score 1):

Destruction is the best way to delete something.

```
self.listNode.destroy()
```

and then add Your data again to your `ListBox`.

Answer (score 1):

**You can Distroy list node like this**

```
from tkinter import *

self.listnodes.delete(0, END) *
```

Comment: You could just edit your previous answer to include this, rather than posting a new answer for just one line of code.